# Variable changing on its own?

Tags: c#, linq

Just look at this GIF — can you see a statement that changes the value of `j`?

https://imgur.com/a/tjDmstd

Here's my code, if needed:

```cs
for (int j = 0; j < types[i].GenericParameters.Count(); j++)
{
    // typeDocs is XElement
    // types[i].GenericParameters is a collection of objects (classes) with properties Name and Description

    string value = FindElementValueByName(typeDocs, "typeparam",
        types[i].GenericParameters.ElementAt(j).Name);
    types[i].GenericParameters = types[i].GenericParameters.Select((p, index) =>
    {
        if (index == j) p.Description = value;
        return p;
    });
}
```

And here's the `FindElementValueByName` method:

```cs
private string FindElementValueByName(XElement root, string searchFor, string compareTo)
{
    return root.Elements(searchFor).FirstOrDefault(p =>
    {
        string? name = p.Attribute("name")?.Value;
        if (name == null) return false;
        return name == compareTo;
    })?.Value ?? string.Empty;
}
```

What's truly amazing me is the fact that `j` is a struct (`int`) and therefore should not change when passed to a method or anywhere!

FYI: I know the `Select` statement is not really necessary here. I tried to use `types[i].GenericParameters.ElementAt(j).Description = value;` but **the `Description` property wasn't being set**. In my current code, it is still not set after `Select`.

Comment: Your `for` loop is altering the value of `j`, as one would expect (`j++`).

Comment: Have you looked at the GIF? Its value changes before next iteration.

Comment: It's a debugging artifact. In normal execution, the line `if (index == j)` is never reached because the `Select` statement isn't executed. That's one of the reasons why you should never mutate objects in a Select statement.

Comment: Yes, assignment doesn't execute it. Until somewhere something  `types[i].GenericParameters.ToList()` is done nothing will execute the `Select`. And *when* it's executed it wil be with the value if `j` that was captured in the lambda statement. All of this makes the code hard to predict, i.e. buggy. Always use LINQ statements with immutability in mind. Don't get tempted to execute the `Select` just to make it "work".

Comment: @GertArnold A little question: would it be potentially dangerous if I used `Select` as in my question without mutating objects in the original sequence, but instead returning new objects created from existing ones (in the way you work with records)?

Comment: Can't answer that w/o knowing how this code is embedded in the rest of the code. It's obviously a great difference whether objects are replaced or modified.

Comment: @GertArnold It just fills in all items in the `types` array. All items are classes that have properties like `Summary`, `Notes`, `GenericParameters` etc which are filled from an XML file containing exported C# documentation comments. Each of the `GenericParameters` (classes) has properties `Name` and `Description`. So this is basically an XML parser. **Thanks for your time!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capture `j` in the lambda passed to the `Select`, which has a lazy evaluation. If you use a code analyzer or ReSharper you must get some warning about its [possible side effect](https://unicorn-dev.medium.com/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6).

In your recording there is no 2nd iteration (maybe because the type has only 1 generic parameter but we cannot see that) so you already left the `for` when the lambda passed to the `Select` is getting executed but by that time `j` has its final value.

A possible hotfix if you force the immediate evaluation of the `Select` by appending it with a `.ToList().` or `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the deferred execution :(